# Not able to post a first question at all due to 40 minute rule?

Tags: bug

I've tried to post my first question on the site, but I get this error when I try to post:

[image]

However, when looking at my profile (to confirm that there is no duplicate submission that occurred), I haven't asked a single question on the site:

[image]

What's happening here? I don't understand. I'm just trying to ask a question on the site. Other network sites don't have this restriction, either; does anyone know why it was instituted?

I attempted to ask this on the English Language Stack Exchange Meta, but it gave me the same timer.

I just confirmed a new account on the site. But somehow, I've already posted - but there's no activity on my account. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide). In particular, the **Asking** section of the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/562482) which states the 40 minute check "... applies to the user's IP address, *not* their account", which is what is most likely what is happening in your case, i.e., somebody else who is rated limited using the same IP address has recently posted a question.

Comment: Also, the timer is "40 minutes since [your] last question anywhere on the network" - if you ask a question on *any other site* it will start the timer